# Can I use favicon of other websites when I link to them on my site?

Tags: links, legal, copyright, favicon, trademark

I'm creating websites catalog and I wonder whether or not I can use favicon of other websites as an icon next to its domain name. As far as I know I can use screenshots of websites without the owner's permission if it is a fair use. What about favicon?

Answer (score 2):

You may need permission to use other brands, logos, and such.  Some will let you download icons and banners.

Comment: What about from an SEO standpoint?

Comment: link your site with html.